# Laravel 7 events are not broadcasting on pusher

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Hi everyone I would like to send the notification and then broadcast it. I follow all the steps and successfully notifications sending and receiving but I don't know what happened it stopped broadcasting my events only notifications are still saving in the database. Can anyone please tell me what is the issue? thanks in advance.

Below is my SendNotiffication Controller

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
    
    use App\Events\AttachmentEvent;
    use App\Events\MessageEvent;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Notifications\AttachmentNotification;
    use App\Notifications\MessageNotification;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Notification;
    
    class SendNotificationController extends Controller
    {
        public function sendNotification( $recipients_list, $type, $message, $data_params ){
            $recipients = $recipients_list;
            if (isset($recipients) && $recipients != NULL) {
                $data = $data_params;
                $message = $message;
                Notification::send($recipients, new MessageNotification($data,$type,$message));
                foreach ($recipients as $key => $usr) {
                    event(new MessageEvent($usr, $data));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my MessageEvent

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;
    public $newTask;
    public function __construct($user,$newTask)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->newTask = $newTask;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastWith(){
        $newNotification = $this->user->unreadNotifications->first();
        return [
            'newNotification' => $newNotification
        ];

    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('message');
        return new Channel('user.'. $this->user->id);
    }
}
```

In my TasksController, I include the SendNotificationController like this

```
protected $AttachmentsController;
    protected $SendNotificationController;
    public function __construct(AttachmentsController $AttachmentsController, SendNotificationController $SendNotificationController)
    {
        $this->AttachmentsController = $AttachmentsController;
        $this->SendNotificationController = $SendNotificationController;
    }
```

Below is my taskPriority function to change the priority and send the notification

```
public function TaskPriority($id){

        $data = preg_split('/\d+\K/', $id);
        $id = $data[0];
        $priority = $data[1];
        $logedInuser = auth('sanctum')->user();
        $user_id = $logedInuser->id;
        if (isset($user_id) && $user_id != NULL) {
            $task = Task::find($id);
            $task->priority = $priority;
            $task->save();
        }

        // ========================================================================================================== //
        // ==========================================  ACTIVITY PERFORMED  ========================================== //
        // ========================================================================================================== //

        $this->saveActivity('task', $task->id,'priority',$task->assignee_id,'Changed task Priority');

        // ========================================================================================================== //
        // ========================================== SENDING NOTIFICATION ========================================== //
        // ========================================================================================================== //

        $recipients = [];
        $recipients = $this->getRecipients($task->id);
        $recipients = array_filter($recipients);

        $type = "task_priority";
        $message = $logedInuser->name.' has changed the priority of the task '.$task->title.' to '.$task->priority;
        $data = [
            'task_id' => $task->id,
            'route' =>'task',
            'data' => $task,
        ];

        $this->SendNotificationController->sendNotification( $recipients, $type, $message, $data );

        return response()->json('The Priority successfully updated');
    }
```

and here in the notification view, I get all the notifications related to the user.

```
<template>
  <div class="notifications ">
    <div class="title">
      <a @click="notificationsShowHide"
        >Notifications {{ unReadNotifications.length }} <i class="fa fa-bell"></i
      ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="noti_panel" v-if="show">
      <div class="notif_listing">
        <div class="top_panel">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <button class="text-left">See all notifications</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <button class="text-right">Mark all as read</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
        <li
          v-for="(notif, key) in unReadNotifications"
          :key="key"
        >
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'task_status'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }} <br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-battery-half"></i>Task status changed</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'attachment'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>New Attachment</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'task_update'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Task updated</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'task_priority'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>Task Priority changed</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'task_created'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Task ceated</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'new_comment'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>New Comment</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'task_delete'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Task Deleted</span></a>
          <a v-if="notif.data.type == 'discussion'" href="javascript:;" @click="markAsUnread(notif)">{{ notif.data.message }}<br><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Discussion Created</span></a>
          <button @click="removeNotification(notif)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import User from "../apis/User";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: "",
      unReadNotifications: [],
      current_notif:'',
      message:'',
      user: "",
      type:null,
    };
  },
  computed:{
    // ...mapGetters(['user'])
  },
  methods: {
    notificationsShowHide() {
      if (this.show == true) {
        this.show = false;
      } else {
        this.show = true;
      }
    },
    markAsUnread(notif){
      this.$store.dispatch("relatedTasks", notif.data.data.data.project_id);
        User.markAsUnread(notif)
        .then(response => {
          if (notif.data.data.route == 'task') {
            this.$store.dispatch({
                type: 'getRelatedAttachments',
                referenceId: notif.data.data.task_id, // reference ID
                attachmentType: notif.data.data.route // task
            });
            this.$store.dispatch({
                type: 'getCommentById',
                referenceId: notif.data.data.task_id, // reference ID
                entityName: notif.data.data.route // task
            });
            this.$router.push('/taskDetail/'+notif.data.data.task_id).catch(()=>{})
          }
          if (notif.data.data.route == "subtask") {
            this.$store.dispatch({
                type: 'getRelatedAttachments',
                referenceId: notif.data.data.subtask_id, // reference ID
                attachmentType: notif.data.data.route // subtask
            });
            this.$store.dispatch({
                type: 'getCommentById',
                referenceId: notif.data.data.subtask_id, // reference ID
                entityName: notif.data.data.route // task
            });
            this.$router.push('/SubTaskDetail/'+notif.data.data.subtask_id).catch(()=>{})
          }
          this.unReadNotifications.splice(notif, 1);
        })

    },
    removeNotification(notif) {
      User.removeNotification(notif)
      .then(response => {
        this.notif_count--;
        this.unReadNotifications.splice(notif, 1);
        if (this.unReadNotifications.length == 0) {
          this.show = false
        }
      })
    },
    getAuthUser() {
      User.getAuthUser()
      .then(response => {
        this.user = response.data
        // console.log(response.data.id)
          window.Echo.channel("user." + response.data.id).listen(
            "MessageEvent",
            e => {
              console.log(e)
              this.unReadNotifications.unshift(e.newNotification);
              this.message = e.message
              this.type = e.type
              // this.$toastr.s("New notification");
            }
          );
      });
    },
    getUserUnReadNotifications(){
      User.getUserUnReadNotifications()
      .then(response => {
        this.unReadNotifications = response.data
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getAuthUser();
    this.getUserUnReadNotifications()
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for myself by running

```
php artisan queue:work
```